# SSIS Package for dynamic Souce database

Tags: sql-server, oracle, ssis, package

i want to know whether the Following is possible and if so please explain in detail. thanks.

In SQL we have Table1 which has many Oracle server connection details. what we have to do is, we need to copy data from Oracle.Table5 to SQl.Table5. the condition is in SQL.Table5 i know the factory name and using the factory name i can get the oracle server details in SQL.Table1. so using the oracle server details i need to connect to oracle and get the matching data and then update in Sql.Table5. Is this possible in SSIS package?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to do that in SSIS. One way of doing it is using dynamic connection strings:

http://sql-bi-dev.blogspot.pt/2010/07/dynamic-database-connection-using-ssis.html

http://kevine323.blogspot.pt/2012/04/dynamic-connection-strings-in-ssis.html

This is all the detail i can give you considering the question.